# How to roll back a WordPress plugin update?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Yesterday I updated WordPress SEO by Yoast to version 1.2.8.4 from version 1.2.7 and now my admin panel is messed up. I searched through the support forum but the plugin author has not replied to the existing threads related to same update issues.

So I think a roll back to a previous version of plugin would be the best option until a fix to the above issue is released by the plugin author.

I have database backup files and my home directory backup files available. I searched in the WordPress forums but couldn't find exact details on how to roll back a plugin update.

Can someone here guide me with the procedure or refer me to a solution?

Answer (score 12):

Unless the plugin has made significant database changes, you could follow these steps to downgrade it:

1. Download and extract the old version from the plugin repository
2. Disable the plugin
3. Log on to your server with FTP or SSH
4. Upload the old plugin directory to wp-content/plugins/. (You would want to overwrite the newer version.)
5. Reactivate the plugin

Here's SEO by Yoast [version 1.2.7](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-seo.1.2.7.zip)

Comment: In addition to this, you can go back to any previous version of the plugin. Here's the link for downloads - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/developers/

Comment: Thanks.. I will overwrite previous plugin files and database

Comment: I did exactly as suggested by Misund but the admin panel is still messed up. I even restored my old database but to no effect. Deactivating the plugin solves all issues. But I don't know why it's still happening even now when I have rolled back to version 1.2.7?

Comment: So you have restored your files to the way they were when everything was fine, and also restored your database to the way it was when everything was fine? In that case, everything _should_ be fine.

Have you changed anything else?

Comment: Worth knowing that you can now upload the old version of the plugin using the normal manual upload process through WordPress itself.  That is, Dashboard > Plugins > Add New > Upload Plugin (near top of page).

Answer (score 2):

There's now a plugin that does this very easily called WP Rollback
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rollback/

It does NOT account for any database changes your plugin may have done between versions so backups and common sense best practices are still really important. But for your basic rollback or even incremental rolling forward of really outdated versions this is really valuable.